# Using return statement in a for loop

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, return-value

I have a class `TemperatureCalculator` that computes which kind of day it was and which one was the hottest. It operates on a vector. The vector is filled by the user's input. Everything works fine except the function `klimaTag()`.

I know why it doesn't work the way it should but I don't know how to fix it without using `std::cout` instead of using the `return` statement.
The function should be replaced by the string. In my implementation it gives out "Sommertag" for every number in the vector which isn't correct.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TemperatureCalculator {
private:
    std::vector<float> temperatures;

public:
    TemperatureCalculator(std::vector<float> temperatures) {
        this->temperatures = temperatures;
    }

    std::string klimaTag() {
        for (std::vector<float>::iterator i = temperatures.begin(); i != temperatures.end(); i++) {
            if (*i >= 25 and *i < 30) {
                return "Sommertag";
            }
            else if (*i >= 30 and *i < 35) {
                return "Heißer Tag";
            }
            else if (*i >= 35) {
                return "Wüstentag";
            }
            else {
                return "Normaltag";
            }
        }
    }

    float maxNumber() {
        float current_max = 0;
        for (std::vector<float>::iterator i = temperatures.begin(); i != temperatures.end(); i++) {
            if (*i > current_max) {
                current_max = *i;
            }
        }
        return current_max;
    }

    void get_user_input() {
        int numberDays;
        std::cout << "Wie viele Tage möchten Sie auswerten?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> numberDays;
        
        float current_temp;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numberDays; i++) {
            std::cout << "Hoechsttemp für Tag " << i + 1 << " eingeben: ";
            std::cin >> current_temp;
            temperatures.push_back(current_temp);
        }
    }

    std::vector<float> get_temperature() {
        return this->temperatures;
    }

};

int main()
{
    TemperatureCalculator t({});
    t.get_user_input();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < t.get_temperature().size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Tag " << i + 1 << " ist ein " << t.klimaTag() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << t.maxNumber();
}
```

Comment: A return breaks the for loop. Hence your klimaTag function will loop over temperatures but only ever return one value corresponding to the first item in the temperatures vector.

Comment: You don't need a loop in `klimaTag` at all, instead you should pass `i` to it as an argument.

Comment: Consider this: you have a loop over the days. Inside you call a method that itself loops over the days. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, how to fix it. I will try to keep as much of your code as possible so you can see the changes that matter the most.

In klimaTag:

```
std::string klimaTag(int index) {
    float temperature = temperatures[index];
    if (temperature >= 25 and temperature < 30) {
        return "Sommertag";
    }
    else if (temperature >= 30 and temperature < 35) {
        return "Heißer Tag";
    }
    else if (temperature >= 35) {
        return "Wüstentag";
    }
    else {
        return "Normaltag";
    }
}
```

In main() :

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < t.get_temperature().size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Tag " << i + 1 << " ist ein " << t.klimaTag(i) << std::endl;
    }
...
```

Why these changes?
Because before, you looped through `temperatures` twice. One time in main, and another in `klimaTag`. Each time you call `klimaTag`, it looks at temperatures[0], sees that it is between 25 and 30, and returns Sommertag. Nothing more can happen after `return`.

Comment: And the code in that `if ... else if` ladder can be simplified by rearranging it a bit: `if (temperature < 25) ... else if (temperature < 30) ... else if (temperature < 35) ... else ...`. +1.

Comment: Right, that's true. Only just realised that op uses `and` instead of `&&` and it ... works? Learn something new every day.

Comment: Yes, `and` is an unfortunate sop to Python programmers. <g>